# WPF: Loaded event never fires when view is instatiated from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a UserControl that is composed of many other UserControls (including a 3rd party control).  When I add this UserControl to my main application view, everything works fine.  However, if I instantiate this view (UserControl) in code, and make the following calls, it doesn't render properly:

```
var pageView = new TemplatePageView() { DataContext = new PageViewModel() };
pageView.Measure(new Size(816, 1056));
pageView.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(816, 1056)));
pageView.UpdateLayout();
```

In this use case, various parts don't display properly.  I have had issues with a 3rd party graphing control in the past rendering, and generally a call to Invalidate fixes it.  So I tried hooking into the Loaded event and calling Invalidate.  This call executes when the view is put in my main application view, but the Loaded event never fires when I instantiate this view in code.  Is there an additional step I need to perform in code?

As a side note, I am doing this in order to send the view to a piece of code for output to a report.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: I'm in the same situation (instantiating a UserControl in code and rendering it to a bitmap), and running into the same problem..Loaded event never fires.  Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think here you are missing to  subscribe Loaded event

```
pageView.Loaded += pageView_Loaded;
......
......
void pageView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Do ur loaded stuff here
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't show it here...but I am doing so in the constructor of a child user control which obviously gets hit...but the loaded handler only gets hit when the control is part of the main application view.

Comment: for that you will have to make the usercontrol part of the Window only then it will fire .Creating an instance doesnt fire Loaded event